# how to add new font to salesforce to use in community and lightning component

Tags: community, lightning, style, font

How can I add new font to use in community and lightning component, should I use static resource or what ?

Comment: Yes. Static resource

Comment: Depends on the type of template your community is using.

Comment: thanks for you answers .. but @Animesh how it depends ?

Comment: If you are not using custom lightning components in community, you need to export assets in the community using Site.com studio.